# Make breadcrumb with Gretel in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, breadcrumbs

I have a problem. I'm using version Gretel 2.1 and Rails 4 and put breadcrumbs.rb in config/ and after remove

```
Gretel::Crumbs.layout do ... end
```

and I just add

```
crumb :root do
  link "Home", root_path
end
```

And put in my application.html.haml this:

```
= breadcrumbs :pretext => "Você está aqui: ", :separator => " &rsaquo;"
```

But don't render nothing, just empty, what make?

Answer (score 2):

Did you call "- breadcrumb :root" in view?

Also try this:

```
= breadcrumbs :pretext => "Você está aqui: ", :separator => " &rsaquo;", :display_single_fragment => true
```

This **:display_single_fragment** option means:

> Whether it should display the breadcrumb if it includes only one link.

and its default value is **false**. See [details here](https://github.com/lassebunk/gretel)

Answer (score 0):

Was facing same issue. was trying with

`- breadcrumbs pretext: "You are here: ", separator: " &rsaquo;"`

Resolved with this

`= breadcrumbs pretext: "You are here: ", separator: " &rsaquo;"`